# NodeJS Issue with huge data export

Tags: node.js, node-mssql, exceljs

I have a scenario. In DB, I have a table with a huge amount of records (2 million) and I need to export them to xlsx or csv.

So the basic approach that I used, is running a query against DB and put the data into an appropriate file to download.

#### Problems:

1. There is a [DB timeout](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#general-same-for-all-drivers) that I have set to 150 sec which sometimes isn't
   enough and I am not sure if expanding timeout would be a good idea!
2. There is also some certain timeout with [express request](http://derpturkey.com/increase-request-timeout-for-express-4/), So it basically timed out my HTTP req and hits for second time (for unknown reason)

So as a solution, I am thinking of using [stream](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#streaming) DB connection and with that if in any way I can provide an output stream with the file, It should work.

So basically I need help with the 2nd part, In stream, I would receive records one by one and at the same time, I am thinking of allowing user download the file progressively. (this would avoid request timeout)

I don't think it's unique problem but didn't find any appropriate pieces to put together. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you see it in your log, do you run the query more than once?
Does your UI timeout before the server even reach the res.end()?